# News Detail View Controller form

Tags: ios, swift

I have a NewsTableViewController and NewsDetailViewController that has to contain a titleLabel, subtitleTextView and imageView.
How to do it right? To place title, subtitle(larger than window) and image in a scroll view or in a cell of table view?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no right answer to this question, it all depends on the design of the graphical user interface that you want.

Personally I would say that you should place the two labels (title and subtitle), an imageview and a textview (the body of the news story) in a scrollview. You could also place the title outside the scrollview if it should be visible at all times or you could place it in some other place, it will all depend on your desired design.

The reason why I am recommending this over the tableview solution is that it will allow for more customisability.

Comment: that's what i wanted to hear

Comment: Also as a another reason, it will require much less code for the scrollview option since you can do most of the work in a storyboard and wont have to create several custom table cells